# Xml Namespace - Coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, namespaces

I need to build an xml document with a namespace. When I create the root element, I define all the necessary namespaces with `xmlAttribute[xmlns]`. But after that, when I create a child element this namespace reference is also shown. What do I need to do about that?

Here is my code example

```
my_doc = XmlNew();
my_doc.xmlRoot = XmlElemNew(my_doc,"Invoice");
my_doc.xmlRoot.XmlAttributes["xmlns"] = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2';
    my_doc.xmlRoot.XmlAttributes["xmlns:cbc"] = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2';
    my_doc.Invoice.XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(my_doc,"cbc:UBLVersionID");
    my_doc.Invoice.XmlChildren[1].XmlText = '2.0';
```

and the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
</Invoice>
```

However the `UBLVersionID` element should look like this. I do not want the child element to show the namespace again.

```
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
```

Comment: please can anyone answer about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just build the XML object yourself (without using the built-in functions).  Something like:

```
<cfsavecontent var="my_doc">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
        <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    </Invoice>
</cfsavecontent>
```

The variable `my_doc` will now contain the XML in your preferred format.

Comment: @AKBAL Neither of those things should be an issue when you do it this way.